# Error message "could not build module 'Foundation'"

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I searched for this question and could not find much help.

Error:

> could not build module 'Foundation'

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 24):

I was able to solve this using the solution provided in this Apple Support Communities [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24766902#24766902):

> The real problem here is at Build Settings in the session: Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - Modules, we should set Enable Modules (C and Objective C) to NO

Comment: Since links can die, i'll post the content here:
The real problem here is at Build settings in the session:
Apple LLVM 5.0 - language - Modules,
we should set Enable Modules (C and objective c) as NO

Comment: If you require modules, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47328607/435129 may solve.

Answer (score 10):

The suggested fix to set `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` did not solve this issue for me.

What did is renaming my `someFile.c` files to `someFile.m`. Even though those files contain just C functions (that do use Foundation types), naming them `.c` produces this error.

Answer (score 8):

I found that if you use some external C / C++ code in your project, you have to remove all the #import in the prefix. That's quite a headache, but it's a true problem.

Comment: I was using CKImageAdditions and then removed my .pch file which then removed all of the build errors.

Comment: What do you mean by this? If I change "#import Dependency.h" to "import Dependency.h" the files no longer build...

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> solved above error for me.

Comment: Aka clean your build folder

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

In your .pch file, write like this:

```
#ifndef PureStandard_PrefixHeader_pch
#define PureStandard_PrefixHeader_pch
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import "A.h"
#import "B.h"
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708926/xcode-9-could-not-build-module-foundation/47328607#47328607):

Set ***Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules*** to **YES** in target's Build Settings

I was seeing the issue on this line in a .m file that is being built as part of an extension:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a `Precompiled Header` where I had includes that included `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` The solution for me was to wrap the include in a

```
#ifdef __OBJC__ 
#include SomeIncludeWithFoundation.h 
#endif
```

You may also see in your `.pch` files something like:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
#ifndef FOUNDATION_EXPORT
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern "C"
#else
#define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

Be sure your modules are included in the right place in your `Precompiled Header`

Answer (score 2):

None of the given solutions worked for me.
I have a project with mixed source codes (**C** and **Objective-C**) and the problem was given by a `.c` which included a shared `.h` which in turn included the **Foundation** header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

In order to solve the problem I had to perform the following steps:

- In the .c that was causing the problem add as first include/import statement: 
  `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`
   You can keep the same import statement in the shared header if you need.
- In the project settings select the entry under **Targets** then click
  on **Build Phases** -> **Compile Sources**. In the **Compiler Flags**
  add `-x objective-c`. This will force the compilation of the **C** source code as **Objective-C** to allow the linking with the **Foundation** framework and since **Objective-C** can embed **C** source code this is perfectly legal.
- In the project settings select the entry under **Targets** then click on **Build Phases** -> **Link Binary With Libraries**. Add the `Foundation.framework` library in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved by change Build System to Legacy Build System

- Open the *ios/PROJECT_NAME.workspace* file
- Then in the top menu, select *File* → *Workspace Settings*
- Then change *Build System* to *Legacy Build System*

Answer (score 0):

Just **rename** your Objective-C++ file **from `*.c` to `*.mm`.**

The errors are gone that way. It handles all the imports just fine this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
- Menu *File* → *Workspace Settings* → *Legacy Build System*
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem, but the errors would for some reason not cause the build to fail, so they were like fake errors, and I made them go away by quitting Xcode, and deleting `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName`