# Xcode 9 "could not build module ‘Foundation’"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I archive an iPhone project, it returns a failure:

> Could not build module "Foundation".

However, when I debug on the iPhone, it runs successfully.

I tried to set ‘Enable Modules’ to No and it seems normal, but another 3rd party library I'm using requires modules be turned on.

What do I do in that case? How do I import social now?

Answer (score 9):

Set to **YES** target's **Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules** in **Build Settings**.

Comment: What are the implications of that? @dimazava

Answer (score 1):

Only reinstalling Xcode worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after trying to build a third party library. It made a symbolic link in the iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include to a non-existent header file in iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include.

After deleting the bad symbolic link, Xcode started building correctly again.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using CocoaPods you could try:

1. Remove your `pod.lock` file
2. Remove your `node_modules`
3. `yarn install` in root directory
4. `cd ios`
5. `pod install`
6. Clean build folder
7. Build