# Could not build module Foundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using a sub-project which has a C++ library that it uses and this project has a SDK that I am trying to use.

I have several projects that I am trying to build, each of which use this SDK. I have some targets that compile fine but then I have some that tell me `Could not build module: Foundation`.

As I said this happens in some but not all of my targets, I was able to get some to work by clearing the linker flags but this does not fix it on all targets. So it seems weird to me that some targets work fine while others do not.

I have tried:

Removing linker flags

Reinstalling Xcode

Messing with header search paths

Any suggestions? I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999754/could-not-build-module-foundation

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["could not build module 'Foundation'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999754/could-not-build-module-foundation)

Answer (score 3):

As don't have more information in question here.
Try making

> Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules

to `Yes` in your **Build Settings**.